# Show text or image if MySQL returns certain string

Tags: php, mysql

What would I do if I wanted my PHP script to show some text or an image if the value of 'count' from a user equals 11? Example, In the URL I have count.php?ID=(ID) and the page displays their ID and their current count. I would like an image or some text to display if their 'count' equals 11.

If you could help in any way, that'd be great! Thanks!

Comment: Is `count` a variable passed in via HTTP request, or is that a database value?  If the latter, you need to include information about your database table structure and your SQL query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$toPrint = ($row["count"] == 11) ? "<img src=\"image.jpg\" alt=\"11\" />" : $row["count"];
echo $toPrint;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to know if a user has a 'count' of greater than 10? If they do display and image or some text, else I assume dispay another message?

An example with my assumptions is:

```
$userid = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['userid']);

$query = mysql_query("SELECT user_id, COUNT(*) as count FROM user WHERE user_id = '$id' GROUP BY user_id HAVING count = 11");
if (mysql_num_rows($query) > 0) {
    // 11 - Display Image or Text
} else {
    // Anything other than 11 - Display something else
}
```